# Is it possible to write in ORC format using hdfs2FileSink operator into HDFS in IBM infosphere streams or any other way?

Tags: ibm-streams

Is it possible to write in ORC format using hdfs2FileSink operator in IBM infosphere streams

NA

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't possible at this time using the HDFS2FileSink operator. It only supports text or binary.

The [streamsx.parquet toolkit](https://github.com/IBMStreams/streamsx.parquet/tree/master/com.ibm.streamsx.parquet) has support for writing to Parquet.

Otherwise, you would have to create your own Java operator that will receive the data and use the ORC API to write the data.

It is fairly straightforward to create a Java operator, [as shown in this video](https://developer.ibm.com/streamsdev/videos/video-create-a-java-operator-in-1-minute/). 
The [Java Operator Development guide](http://ibmstreams.github.io/streamsx.documentation/docs/java/java-op-dev-guide/#java-operator-development-guide) can walk you through the process. Specifically see [writing a sink operator](http://ibmstreams.github.io/streamsx.documentation/docs/java/java-op-dev-guide/#creating-a-sink-operator).

After creating a new Java operator,  add code to write to the ORC API in the process method:

```
  @Override
public void process(StreamingInput<Tuple> stream, Tuple tuple)
        throws Exception {
    // TODO Insert code here to process the incoming tuple, 
    // typically sending tuple data to an external system or data store.
    // String value = tuple.getString("AttributeName");
}
```

I would start with the  [ORC home page, choose the appropriate link for Hive, Hadoop](https://orc.apache.org/)

Comment: OK, if that works for you please accept the answer. Thanks!